# Block starting of OSGi service until property appears

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, karaf

Lets say I have a bundle with just the following class:

```
class FullName {

  String firstName
  String lastName

  public FullName (String firstName, String lastName){
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

I will instantiate this service by creating an object of class FullName by using the following blueprint config:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="FullNameApp" update-strategy="reload" >
<!-- No default properties -->
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="full-name" class="org.mypackage.FullName">
  <argument value="${first.name}" />
  <argument value="${last.name}" />
</bean>
```

I am using Karaf 3.0. The properties doesn't exist neither does $KARAF_HOME/etc/FullNameApp.cfg. How can I make the start of this bundle block forever until those properties appear?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a good solution for this case in blueprint. You might want to look into declarative services if you need to support this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll educate myself on declarative services.